# Try to get object which is not empty

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object

I'm confused. I have the following code:

```
#import "Array.h"

@implementation Array
@synthesize sections;

-initArray:(NSUInteger)s
{
    if(self=[self init]) { 
       sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:s];
       for (int i=0; i<=s; i++) {

           [sections insertObject:[NSNull null] at Index:i];

       }
    }

    return self;
}
```

// Here is an array filling

```
-(void)setObject:(NSNumber *)object:(NSUInteger)intSection
{
    [sections replaceObjectAtIndex:intSection withObject:object];

}
```

// Try to init and fill an object

```
-(id)initAtAll:(NSMutableArray *)obj
{
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSUInteger i = array.count;

    NSObject* arrayObject = [self initArray:i];
    NSNumber *ggg = [NSNumber numberWithInt:777];
    [self setObject:ggg :0 :0];                       // I got an error;

    return  self;


}
+(id)createObj:(NSMutableArray *)obj
{
   return [[self alloc]initAtAll:(NSMutableArray*)obj];
}


@end
```

in ViewController when i call `createObj` i got an array with empty data. I want to receive an object with data which is not empty.How can i fill it? Thanks

Comment: What on earth is `-initArray:(NSUInteger)s` think your missing the return type. Is this just a typo?

Comment: Also using `init` & `set` prefixes on your methods while they don't do what they supposed to be doing is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you trying to call this method when you get this error:

```
-(void)setObject:(NSNumber *)object:(NSUInteger)intSection
```

The function declaration takes two parameters - object and intSection but when you call it you are passing 3:

```
[self setObject:ggg :0 :0];
```

you can replace it to:

```
[self setObject:ggg :0];
```

And it should do the job but I strongly recommend you to name every parameter when you declare the method, it's easier to read it. You can change the method declaration to:

```
-(void)setObject:(NSNumber *)object section:(NSUInteger)intSection
{
    [sections replaceObjectAtIndex:intSection withObject:object];

}
```

and call it like:

```
[self setObject:ggg section:0];
```

Comment: Oh...it's my mistake. I wrote like that `[self setObject:ggg section:0];` I just write here not so right